TSA PreCheck and Global Entry… Which do I renew?
I had TSA PreCheck before receiving Global Entry. It’s now time to renew my TSA PreCheck. Should I renew it if I have GE, even if I didn’t get TSA PreCheck (or a known traveler number) included with my GE? I’m a little confused on what to do.

You can check your status with your Trusted Traveler Program login. Since GE includes PreCheck, you should now be on the GE renewal schedule, but it is easy to check.

How did you not get precheck included with Global Entry, or what makes you think you did not? I thought it was automatic, and that your GE PASSID serves as a KTN.

Yeah, I got GE late last year, already had precheck and have used my GE PASSID as my KTN both domestically (so my boarding passes had precheck on them) and internationally.

@NateEldredge This is why I’m confused because I enrolled in TSA PreCheck separate from GE. And when I enrolled in GE I did not select to include TSA PreCheck with my GE since I already had it separately.  Now I’m understanding that both are separate agencies but either of their enrollment works the same for domestic or international travel. Long story short, I only need to renew one or the other (not both).

Yes, right. "I did not select to include TSA PreCheck with my GE": Was it even an option to select it or not? I thought it was automatic.
